# Display QListView as pop for search results

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to implement a search functionality where a user enters a keyword(s) and then a '`listview`' or '`tableview`' shows up underneath the search bar.

I've tried testing this with a qtable by using code like:

```
QStandardItemModel *myModel = NULL;
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(myModel);
view->show();
```

The problem with this is that it shows a table in a window. I would like to have something like a popup displaying below the search bar using fixed x and y co-ordinates and maybe a fixed width and height. I was reading up and I saw that I might be able to implement a qpixmap. But I also need the popup to display ontop or of a horizontal layout.

Comment: See QCompleter...

Comment: and in addition to @eyllanesc, take a look at the ***QSortFilterProxyModel***